# Cant resolve task for exam.(Tree in C)

Tags: c

My task is going like this:

> Write a recursive function `int calculate(node *root, int lvl, int defaultlvl)` that will calculate the sum of all nodes at the default lvl and all progenys of those nodes.

I got in my task this information.

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *left, *right;
} node;
```

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. You should really decide which one you are using.

Comment: The assignment is confusing. You probably mean to sum the `value` members of each node, but what is the *default lvl* and how does it apply since you include all descendants (*progenies*) of these nodes?

Comment: And what is your question? Do you really expect someone just to give you the full solution? Please make an attempt and ask a *specific* question about that attempt. Or ask about something specific that will help you clear an understanding to enable you to progress your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that would calculate the sum of values of nodes which are below the level defaultlvl :

```
int calculate(node *root, int lvl, int defaultlvl){
    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (lvl<defaultlvl)
        return calculate(root->left,lvl+1,defaultlvl) + calculate(root->right,lvl+1,defaultlvl);
    else
        return root.value + calculate(root->left,lvl+1,defaultlvl) + calculate(root->right,lvl+1,defaultlvl);
```

}

NB : You then need to call
`calculate (myroot,1,defaultlvl)` 
to get the expected result, with myroot a pointer to the root node of your tree.

Answer (score 2):

You will not get a answer for homework without showing some effort at trying to solve the problem...

Here is a simple function that sums the whole tree. Modify it to handle the level limitation is the assignment:

```
int calculate(node *root) {
    if (root) {
        return root->value + calculate(root->left) + calculate(root->right);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are having this exam right now, so here you go. Please cite Stackoverflow in your answer :-)

Just a guess that defaultlvl means "sum up nodes from this level on":

```
int calculate(node* root,int lvl, int defaultlvl)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return 0;

    int sum = calculate(root->left, lvl+1, defaultlvl);
    sum += calculate(root->right, lvl+1, defaultlvl);

    if (lvl >= defaultlvl)
        sum += root->value;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thx dude a lot ! can i set int sum =calculate(root->left, lvl+1, defaultlvl) + calculate(root->righ,lvl+1,defaultlvl);   instead of writing sum+=calculate(root->right, lvl+1, defaultlvl) ????